# represent and sorting polynomial using linked list IN C

Tags: c

Help me please. Code below is made to represent the polynomial function and sorting that polynomial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PolyNode *pnode;
typedef struct PolyNode {
    float coef;
    int expon;
    pnode next;
};

pnode Make_Node(pnode ptr, float coef, int expon) {
    ptr->coef = coef;
    ptr->expon = expon;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

pnode Input_Node(pnode ptr, float coef, int expon) {
    if (ptr->expon < expon || ptr) {
        pnode temp = NULL;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(pnode));
        temp = Make_Node(temp, coef, expon);
        temp->next = ptr;
        ptr = temp;
        return ptr;
    } else {
        pnode temp = NULL;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(pnode));
        temp = Make_Node(temp, coef, expon);
        pnode pol;
        pol = ptr;
        while (pol->next && pol->next->expon > expon) {
            pol = pol->next;
        }
        temp->next = pol->next;
        pol->next = temp;
        return ptr;
    }
}

void Print_Pol(pnode ptr) {
    pnode temp;
    temp = ptr;
    while (temp) {
        printf("%gx^%d", temp->coef, temp->expon);
        if (temp->next != NULL) {
            printf(" + ");
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    pnode ptr;
    ptr = (pnode)malloc(sizeof(pnode));
    ptr = Make_Node(ptr, 2, 3);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 2, 4);
    printf("%s%d\n", &ptr, ptr->expon);
    ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 3, 6);
    printf("%s%d\n", &ptr, ptr->expon);
    // ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 3, 7);

    Print_Pol(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

help me! when I erase the "//" before //ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 3, 7); the program does not run.

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef!  It confuses everyone, including you.

Comment: it does not run even when this comment is on

Comment: I'd recommend putting the error output as text in the question; there's less guarantee your image links will continue working over time.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be that you are not allocating enough space for each node.  Given this code:

```
pnode ptr;
ptr = (pnode) malloc(sizeof(pnode));
```

Type `pnode` is a *pointer* type, so you are allocating enough space for a pointer.  What you need is enough space for a `struct PolyNode`, which is necessarily larger than a `pnode` because it contains one among its several members.  I recommend writing allocations in this form:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

The key point is that the amount of space to allocate is defined in terms of the size of the referrent of the desired result, rather than in terms of an explicit type.  That protects you from specifying the wrong type, and it does not need to be changed if ever you change the type to which the pointer points.

Secondarily, you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C (though you do in C++), and you should not do so.

Do note that you have faulty allocations in several places in the code you present.  Make sure to fix all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You do not allocate enough memory with `malloc(sizeof(nodep))`: `sizeof(nodep)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the structure.  You should instead use `malloc(sizeof(struct PolyNode))`.

Consider simplifying your code by allocating the memory in `Input_Node()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PolyNode *pnode;
struct PolyNode {
    float coef;
    int expon;
    pnode next;
};

pnode Input_Node(pnode ptr, float coef, int expon) {
    pnode temp = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    temp->coef = coef;
    temp->expon = expon;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (ptr == NULL || ptr->expon < expon) {
        temp->next = ptr;
        ptr = temp;
    } else {
        pnode pol = ptr;
        while (pol->next && pol->next->expon > expon) {
            pol = pol->next;
        }
        temp->next = pol->next;
        pol->next = temp;
    }
    return ptr;
}

void Print_Pol(pnode ptr) {
    pnode temp = ptr;
    while (temp) {
        printf("%gx^%d", temp->coef, temp->expon);
        if (temp->next != NULL) {
            printf(" + ");
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    pnode ptr = Input_Node(NULL, 2, 3);
    ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 2, 4);
    ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 3, 6);
    ptr = Input_Node(ptr, 3, 7);
    Print_Pol(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```